# Edit cookies in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, internet-explorer-10

Is there a way to modify a cookie in IE10? (windows 7)

I've tried editing the cookie in the following folder but it had no effect:

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\
```

Comment: Possibly related: [Where are cookies stored in IE11 on Windows 10 (1709)](https://superuser.com/questions/1270605/where-are-cookies-stored-in-ie11-on-windows-10-1709)

Answer (score 2):

You can to use console of IE to edit any value of cookie

Now first hit below commond

```
document.cookie
```

It will return you some key values. Now use below command to edit or create new key values

```
document.cookie="YOURKEY=YOURVALUE"
```

[image]

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

This application may do what you want. The problem is:

> There is only limited support for Internet Explorer 10.0, due to a change in the way that cookies index information is stored.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/internet_explorer_cookies_view.html

Details about the program:

> IECookiesView is a small utility that displays the details of all cookies that Internet Explorer stores on your computer.
>   In addition, It allows you to do the following actions:

```
Sort the cookies list by any column you want, by clicking the column header. A second click sorts the column in descending order.
Find a cookie in the list by specifying the name of the Web site.
Select and delete the unwanted cookies.
Save the cookies to a readable text file.
Copy cookie information into the clipboard.
Automatically refresh the cookies list when a Web site sends you a cookie.
Display the cookies of other users and from other computers.
Open the IECookiesView utility directly from Internet Explorer toolbar.
Change the content of a cookie !
Export your cookies to Netscape/Mozilla cookies file.
Block specific Web sites from using cookies through the cookies blocking mechanism of Internet Explorer 6.0.
```