# Where are cookies stored in IE11 on Windows 10 (1709)

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer-11, windows-10-v1709

The latest version of Windows 10 (1709 or 10.0.16299.64) seems to have changed where cookies are saved.

Typically, you could find the cookies in the `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies` folder as previously [discussed.](https://superuser.com/a/1151199/691775)

However, with the 1709 update, there is no "Cookies" folder. So where did the cookies go?

Comment: This is not just Windows 10. I can't find my Cookies folder in Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design. If you run `shell:cookies` and activate hidden files in Explorer you see a file called `deprecated.cookie` with this content:

> Cookies are no longer stored in files.  Please use Internet*Cookie*
>   APIs to access cookies.

So Microsoft has changed this and no longer stores them in single files.

Comment: Thanks. It's crazy how InternetGetCookie has been around for years but this is the first i have heard of it.

Comment: This is **not** answering the answer. You just answer that cookies are no longer there, but you don't say where are they now? How to read cookies on IE?

Answer (score 0):

Open RUN, type “***shell:cookies***” and end with enter, you should open the folder.

Default location should be:
***C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies***

Also, you can check it via:
IE – Tools - Internet Options – General – Browsing history – Settings – Temporary Internet Files – Current location

Comment: That brings you to the cookies folder, but the folder does seem to be empty after 1709. I have a PC that was upgraded which did have cookies (last dated Oct 22) and a new machine that has nothing. I noticed that my location is also different (INetCache) but that directory does not have cookies either, just the cache.

Comment: @Rakshasas [see my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1270860/174557)